# Error with my unity android app: The scene freezes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen, freeze

I'm having a problem with my unity android app, the scene freezes like this:
Basicly its a scene where the player chooses which off his users he wants to use. It scrolls left or right. I have 10 userspaces which can either be enabled or diasbled.
[image]
[image: This is how ti looks on facebook]

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class active : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject Player_1;
 public GameObject Player_2;
 public GameObject Player_3;
 public GameObject Player_4;
 public GameObject Player_5;
 public GameObject Player_6;
 public GameObject Player_7;
 public GameObject Player_8;
 public GameObject Player_9;
 public GameObject Player_10;
 public GameObject PlusButton;
 int a2;
 int a3;
 int a4;
 int a5;
 int a6;
 int a7;
 int a8;
 int a9;
 int a10;
 int a11;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  float y = Player_1.transform.position.y;
  float z = Player_1.transform.position.z;
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active1") == 1) {
   Player_1.SetActive (true);
   a2 ++;
   a3 ++;
   a4 ++;
   a5 ++;
   a6 ++;
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_1.transform.position = new Vector3 (222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_1.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active2") == 1) {
   Player_2.SetActive (true);
   a3 ++;
   a4 ++;
   a5 ++;
   a6 ++;
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   
   Player_2.transform.position = new Vector3 (a2 * 200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_2.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active3") == 1) {
   Player_3.SetActive (true);
   a4 ++;
   a5 ++;
   a6 ++;
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_3.transform.position = new Vector3 (a3 * 200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_3.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active4") == 1) {
   Player_4.SetActive (true);
   a5 ++;
   a6 ++;
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_4.transform.position = new Vector3 (a4*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_4.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active5") == 1) {
   Player_5.SetActive (true);
   a6 ++;
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_5.transform.position = new Vector3 (a5*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_5.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active6") == 1) {
   Player_6.SetActive (true);
   a7 ++;
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_6.transform.position = new Vector3 (a6*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_6.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active7") == 1) {
   Player_7.SetActive (true);
   a8 ++;
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_7.transform.position = new Vector3 (a7*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_7.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active8") == 1) {
   Player_8.SetActive (true);
   a9 ++;
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_8.transform.position = new Vector3 (a8*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_8.SetActive (false);
  } 
  
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active9") == 1) {
   Player_9.SetActive (true);
   
   a10 ++;
   a11 ++;
   Player_9.transform.position = new Vector3 (a9*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_9.SetActive (false);
  }
  if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("active10") == 1) {
   Player_10.SetActive (true);
   
   a11 ++;
   Player_10.transform.position = new Vector3 (a10*200+222,y,z);
  } else {
   
   Player_10.SetActive (false);
  }
  
  Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (a11 * 200+222 , y, z);
  PlusButton.transform.position = pos;
  
  
  
 }

}
```

What could cause this?

Comment: Please post your code, people can't help without seeing that. Also does this happen on multiple devices? Could the app be too much for the one you're testing with.

Comment: thanks for the note I just did ti